# Visible text in workflow, but invisible in output, is it possible with InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I want text that appears and is editable with ease in InDesign. But, I don't want it to be appear upon output.

These text frames are some text which needs to be shown in variables. I have to anchor them to the main text. So, I can't place them in an non-printable layer.

Is there a check in paragraph style to ignore that in output, or some kind of property somewhere which exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can set **objects** to be non-printable by selecting them and then ticking the `Nonprinting` item on the **Attributes Panel** (Window > Attributes).

This has to be done to the **text frame** not the text itself. There are no Paragraph/Character styles to set text itself to nonprinting.